# Getting a specific index of numpy array by given array element as integer

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

a=np.zeros(5)
a[0]=22
a[1]=33
a[2]=10
a[3]=12
a[4]=49
var=np.where(a==10)
print(var)
```

We are getting the output of the above code as follows :

```
(array([2], dtype=int64),)
```

but, we want to get the **index value only** (eg, 2 here) **as integer**, not the whole line.

Comment: Ok, so you need to understand what the returned object is. Play with it, do var[0] and see what comes out, then keep playing by further indexing.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work for large array with size 15000. Error I'm getting :

FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  var =  np.where(Keys==10)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `np.where`, I guess the only way to get the index would be `np.where(a==10)[0][0]`.

Comment: Sorry, it does not work for large array with size 15000. Error I'm getting :

FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  var =  np.where(Keys==10)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is simple:

```
index = var[0][0]
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work for large array with size 15000. Error I'm getting :

FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  var =  np.where(Keys==10)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> var [0][0]
2
```

but var [0] could be a list if the lookup item has duplicated entries.

Answer (score 0):

Result of [numpy.where(condition)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is either a ndarray or a tuple of ndarrays.
Your result is also a tuple. A better practice for printing out the result will be converting resulting tuple into a single dimension array and then print each value of that array.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([22,33,10,12,49])  #array created with values
var = np.where(a==10)           #condition to check, resulting in tuple with location of matching values
var = np.asarray(var).ravel()   #asarray(var) converts var in array and ravel() converts that into singular array.
for v in var:
    print(v)
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work for large array with size 15000. Error I'm getting :

FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  var =  np.where(Keys==10)